# How to use and edit Windows exceutable resources from C?

Tags: c, windows, resources

Can anyone tell me how to add a Windows string resource?

How to read it?

And, lastly, code for another C program to edit that resource.

thanx a lot in advance...hope you guyz don't laugh ..;)

Comment: So, you want us to write code for you...? Also, what platform? What do you mean by "resource"? Why is this tagged C++ if you want a program in C?

Comment: Your question is vague enough that it will be hard for anyone here to help you.  Please provide more detail as to what you are trying to do.

Comment: This isn't a discussion forum, please use proper punctuation and capitalization in your questions.

Comment: What is a `resource` for you? What's the context?

Comment: Not enough information to answer, or even laugh at you.

Comment: @Sam Most forums I've been to try to enforce proper punctuation and capitalization...

Comment: sorry guyzz..i am not demanding you to write code...let me explain i was writing an app and wanted to store a string in resource so that i can edit that later after building....

Comment: i am sorry sam i am bit addicted to such language cause i mostly used that but ill try mah best to avoid that

Comment: I wish every new user didn't have to undergo a hazing. We could have left this open a little longer until @Dapu had time to rephrase and clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are talking about Windows resources inside of executables, see this:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/dynares.aspx

Comment: ya you absolutely right thanks a ton man.... love u